# c++ integration with travis-ci.org using cppunit

Tags: c++, cppunit, travis-ci

I've got a [very small and simple github project](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/cppLearning) which I would like to integrate with travis-ci.org ([.travis.yml file](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/cppLearning/blob/master/.travis.yml)). Unfortunately, compilation fails ([travis console log](https://travis-ci.org/tkoomzaaskz/cppLearning/builds/9747531)), the compiler cannot find cppunit even though I run `sudo apt-get ...` to install it.

The `test/list_test.h` file has got the following line:

```
#include <cppunit/TestFixture.h>
```

As I said, travis compiler cannot find cppunit headers. Can anyone point me out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake was OK. Travis Script was also OK. But the cppunit package was mistaken. It should be `libcppunit-dev` instead of `libcppunit-1.12-1`

Comment: Great that you got this fixed, and that you came back to update your question. Any chance you could mark this answer as the accepted answer so the question is marked as "answered"? :)